# extract data using loop over tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I have the following tuple containing molecule number (`MolNum`) and corresponding `distance` from certain reference point. The molecules are arranged in ascending order according to `distances`. I can extract `MolNum` and `distances` as two individual lists. However, I would like to get the elements of `g` by satisfying the following condition, `if  10 < distance < 100` ; so I will get `gg`. How I can get this ?

```
g = [(MolNum(378), 2.4613922385709617e-14),
 (MolNum(373), 40.6680008439399),
 (MolNum(353), 72.49296570091882),
 (MolNum(354), 83.18203548933252),
 (MolNum(359), 88.23588863972836),
 (MolNum(372), 97.47433492265824),
 (MolNum(369), 104.59206739018573),
 (MolNum(370), 114.66573137439451),
 (MolNum(361), 122.33788252133775),
 (MolNum(376), 137.2686523522959),
 (MolNum(360), 141.72521396936926),
 (MolNum(371), 145.96842598002533),
 (MolNum(352), 149.8990795114449),
 (MolNum(366), 164.55606071030496),
 (MolNum(358), 180.72531479536423),
 (MolNum(375), 182.21612213617874),
 (MolNum(364), 185.78028496680486),
 (MolNum(363), 192.02220222384793),
 (MolNum(368), 194.0298647708072),
 (MolNum(365), 194.57037736733918),
 (MolNum(356), 201.91526815811372),
 (MolNum(362), 217.8580017023349),
 (MolNum(357), 234.3818585062885),
 (MolNum(374), 241.33751568809993),
 (MolNum(367), 249.36129229747306),
 (MolNum(355), 253.59625354913504)]
```

After satisfying the condition;

```
gg = [(MolNum(373), 40.6680008439399),
 (MolNum(353), 72.49296570091882),
 (MolNum(354), 83.18203548933252),
 (MolNum(359), 88.23588863972836),
 (MolNum(372), 97.47433492265824)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gg = [(mol_num, distance) for mol_num, distance in g if 10 < distance < 100]
```

Comment: nice, thank you a lot. it works !

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
gg = [item for item in g if 10<item[1]<100]
```

Or you may think about @Anand S Kumar is answer of using `filter()`, which is a more **pythonic** way.

Hope it helps

Comment: this works too. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [builtin `filter` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for this, giving the condition as a lambda expression in first argument and the list to filter in second argument -

```
gg = list(filter(lambda x: 10 < x[1] < 100,g))
```

For Python 2.7 , you do not need the `list(...)` as filter returns a list.

---

In Python 3.x, `filter()` function returns an iterator which yields elements where the condition is satisfied (that is the condition returns `True` .

In Python 2.7 ,  `filter()` function returns a list of elements where the condition is satisfied (that is the condition returns `True` .

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> class MolNum:
...     def __init__(self, n):
...             self.n = n
...
>>> g = [(MolNum(378), 2.4613922385709617e-14),
...  (MolNum(373), 40.6680008439399),
...  (MolNum(353), 72.49296570091882),
...  (MolNum(354), 83.18203548933252),
...  (MolNum(359), 88.23588863972836),
...  (MolNum(372), 97.47433492265824),
...  (MolNum(369), 104.59206739018573),
...  (MolNum(370), 114.66573137439451),
...  (MolNum(361), 122.33788252133775),
...  (MolNum(376), 137.2686523522959),
...  (MolNum(360), 141.72521396936926),
...  (MolNum(371), 145.96842598002533),
...  (MolNum(352), 149.8990795114449),
...  (MolNum(366), 164.55606071030496),
...  (MolNum(358), 180.72531479536423),
...  (MolNum(375), 182.21612213617874),
...  (MolNum(364), 185.78028496680486),
...  (MolNum(363), 192.02220222384793),
...  (MolNum(368), 194.0298647708072),
...  (MolNum(365), 194.57037736733918),
...  (MolNum(356), 201.91526815811372),
...  (MolNum(362), 217.8580017023349),
...  (MolNum(357), 234.3818585062885),
...  (MolNum(374), 241.33751568809993),
...  (MolNum(367), 249.36129229747306),
...  (MolNum(355), 253.59625354913504)]
>>>
<filter object at 0x02302E70>
>>> gg = list(filter(lambda x: 10 < x[1] < 100,g))
>>> len(gg)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Pandas, it's a very commonly used package for tabular data analysis of this type:

```
import pandas as pd
g= pd.DataFrame(g)
gg = g[g[1].between(10,100)] 
gg

Out[239]: 
     0          1
1  373  40.668001
2  353  72.492966
3  354  83.182035
4  359  88.235889
5  372  97.474335
```

Comment: thank you for your recommendation. I did not use panda though.